# <p:dataExporter> fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Phrase

Tags: jsf, maven, primefaces, itext

i encounter with problem to export datatable to pdf. I use:

```
<primeFacesVersion>3.5</primeFacesVersion>
```

and:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in xhtml:

```
<h:form id="listForm">

    <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="1">
        <p:dataTable id="listTable" var="employee"
                     value="#{employeeBean.result}" paginator="true" dynamic="true"
                     rows="10" rowKey="#{item.id}" rowIndexVar="i" selection="#{employeeBean.selected}"
                     emptyMessage="#{label['no.record.found']}" sortDescMessage="#{label['sort.desc.message']}"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom" sortAscMessage="#{label['sort.asc.message']}"
                     update="listTable">
.....
      <h:commandLink value="#{label['PDF']}" ajax="false" icon="excel-icon">
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="listTable" fileName="emplList"/>
        </h:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

It is not work an throw this exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com/lowagie/text/Phrase] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Phrase

Comment: double check that you don't have additional iText jars in your class path like 5.x

Comment: I checked it, i don't have any other jar iText file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this,

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

you're basically telling Maven that you've already taken care of that this dependency is guaranteed present in the runtime classpath and thus Maven doesn't need to include it in the build. I.e. the iText JAR file won't end up in WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and it's assumed that the target servletcontainer already provides it out the box (like the Java EE/servlet libraries).

However, no one servletcontainer in the world that I know of has iText bundled among its libraries. Also, if you would actually have modified the servletcontainer's libraries to include iText, then you would surely have explicitly mentioned it in the question. So, I believe that you just made a mistake there in the Maven configuration. Perhaps you copypasted an example Maven coordinate without actually understanding its meaning. Fix it accordingly:

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Or just remove it altogether, it's the default already.

#### See also:

- [Maven dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)